# How Do I Create a $_POST array from textarea input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

Here is what I am trying to do.

I have a textarea input box, I would like to enter in data in an array format like this into that textarea box

```
'key1'='value1'
'key2'='value2'
'key3'='value3'
```

I then want to take this data and use it in my ajax call like so

```
var a = $("textarea#array_box").val().split('\n');
$.ajax({
   url: 'index.php/controller/function',
   type: "POST",
   data: a,
   success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
```

I am trying to get the data to pass in so that in the controller if i did one of the return statements below I would get the resulting output.

```
 return $_POST['key1'] // should return 'value1'
 return $_POST['key2'] // should return 'value2'
 return $_POST['key3'] // should return 'value3'
```

How do I code this so that I can type into my textarea box an array, and pass that array into my controller as a $_POST?

Comment: Why would you want to do that, who is going to type in key/value pairs in an input? Use more inputs, and serialize the form instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter(Boolean)` to remove empty elements from `a` array; `$.each()` to iterate `a` array, `.trim()` to remove space characters, `.replace()` with `RegExp` `/=(?=')/` to replace `=` with `:`; `RegExp` `/'/g` to replace `'` with `"`; create a string to concatenate string at each iteration; `JSON.stringify()` following `$.each()`; pass result of `JSON.stringify()` to `JSON.parse()` as data to `POST`

```
$("button").click(function() {

    var a = $("textarea#array_box").val().split("\n").filter(Boolean);

    var textareaData = "";

    $.each(a, function(key, value) {
      textareaData += value.trim()
                      .replace(/=(?=')/, ":")
                      .replace(/'/g, '"') 
                      + (key < a.length - 1 ? "," : "");
    });
    textareaData = JSON.stringify("{" + textareaData + "}");
    console.log(textareaData);
    $.ajax({
      url: "/echo/json/",
      type: "POST",
      data: JSON.parse(textareaData),
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  });
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ahnegop3/3/

Comment: Where is the code that parses `key1'='value1`? It looks like you're just taking the whole line instead of parsing it.

Comment: @Barmar _"Where is the code that parses key1'='value1? It looks like you're just taking the whole line instead of parsing it."_ `$.each(a, function(key, value) {
  textareaData[prop + (++n)] = value;
});`; try typing at `textarea`, move cursor to next line, type further, press `button` element, see `console` at https://jsfiddle.net/ahnegop3/

Comment: That will set `$_POST['key1'] = "'key1'='value1'"` instead of setting it to just `"value1"`.

Comment: @Barmar  Try typing at `textarea` for example `"abc"`, move cursor to next line, type further e.g., `"123"`, press `button` element, see `console` at https://jsfiddle.net/ahnegop3/

Comment: I get `key1: "'key1'='value1'"`

Comment: It should be `key1: "value1"`

Comment: And if I type `'foo'='bar'`, the object should be `{ foo: "bar" }, but I get `{ key1: "'foo'='bar'" }`

Comment: It seems like you didn't look at the format that he wants the textarea input to be in. The user types the keys and values explicitly, and those should be used as the post parameters.

Answer (score 0):

based on your code, you can do something like this:

```
<?php 
    $tempvar=$_POST['data'];
    $result = array();
    foreach($tempvar as $tempitem){
      $tempitem=str_replace("'","",$tempitem); //we get rid of the ' symbols
      $t=explode("=",$tempitem); //' divide them by the "=" symbol
      $result [$t[0]]=$t[1];
    }

//the result  variable now holds the array
echo $result['key1'] // value1  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

ajax data format must be `{key:value,key,value}` .So to getting that format , you need do a little loop with `$.each` and do assign key and value by like this

> object[key] = value

```
var a = $("textarea#array_box").val().split('\n');
var temp = [];
$.each(a,function(i,v){
      s = v.split("="); //split again with =
      s[0] = s[0].replace(/'/g,""); //remove ' from string
      s[1] = s[1].replace(/'/g,"");
      temp.push(s[0],s[1]);
});
a = {};
//creating data objects
$.each(temp,function(i,v){
    if(i % 2 == 0){
            a[temp[i]] = temp[++i];
    }
});
```